# How do I need to configure Keras model to predict an image?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, image-segmentation

The main task is to predict a mask for the input image. So I have the following data for training:

- lot's of 768x768 original pics like this:

[image]

- and output mask pics(also 768x768) like this:

[image]

Also I have validation original pics.

I prepare some kind of neural model that should predict the output mask. I prepared [keras model configuaration](https://gist.github.com/keipa/54ba9fd1c39ea6d2810dbf836c98ce25) that should have a topology which looks like below:

[image]

The code I prepared for training is there.

```
import keras
epochs=100

image_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()
mask_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()
seed = 1
image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'H:/LABS/ship_detection/test_train/',
    color_mode='rgb',batch_size=32,target_size=(768,768),
    seed=seed)

mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'H:/LABS/ship_detection/test_mask/',
    class_mode="categorical",batch_size=32,target_size=(768,768),
    seed=seed)

train_generator = zip(image_generator, mask_generator)

model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    callbacks=callbacks,steps_per_epoch=1)
```

But when I try to fit generator for prediction I have an issue:

```
c:\users\harwister\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator.py in fit_generator(model, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
    208                     batch_size = list(x.values())[0].shape[0]
    209                 else:
--> 210                     batch_size = x.shape[0]
    211                 batch_logs['batch'] = batch_index
    212                 batch_logs['size'] = batch_size

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I do something wrong for sure, but I can't understand anything from these kind of errors. The simple question I can't find a response in Google is: How can I push into Keras two images (input and output images) for training and after training get an output image providing an input image?

Comment: @today I saw your responce. Currently a have personal issue so, I can't spend some time to check your solution. I'll let you know about results later. Don't worry

Answer (score 0):

Since you have separate generators for the images and the labels (i.e. masks), you need to set the `class_mode` argument to `None` to prevent the generators from producing any labels arrays:

```
image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(class_mode=None, ...)
mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(class_mode=None, ...)
```

This way, `image_generator` would only generate the input images and the `mask_generator` would only generate the mask (i.e. true label) images.